# Branch merge permission in Bitbucket

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch, git-merge

I have started using Bitbucket. My repository name is `project-space`. Within this repo, I have three `branches` , they are `master`, `staging` and `testing` . By default, I can merge the branches with each other. But, I want to set a permission in Bitbucket, where `master` branch can only be merged with `staging` and `staging` branch can be only be merged with `testing`. I have tried `Add a branch permission` but it is giving me option to restrict users only, not branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such setting/permission for bitbucket repo.

If branches are merged by Pull request, the user who approve and merge need to judge manually.